# Структура базы городов

Tags: mysql, php, sql

http://citieslist.ru/

Мне нужна база городов россии белоруссии украины и казахстана
в полном виде

нашел только ту ссылку что сверху

еще нашел

http://ekimoff.ru/103/

но ппц, там всего очень мало

в первом случае мне не нравится структура таблиц

допустим мне нужно искать Витебская область в базе

как думаете это нормально вообще искать по слову, ведь там нет никаких таблиц с id области, все в одной таблице

очень странная структура, в какую ее лучше преобразовать?

Answer (score 2):

что касается России, то есть такая база, которая называется КЛАДР - Классификатор адресов Российской федерации. В ней полный (ну почти, за очень редкими исключениями) список всех населенных пунктов (вплоть до деревень). Помимо этого там же и список улиц, проспектов, переулков. В общем, ваши потребности удовлетворит с головой. Вот [здесь](http://www.gnivc.ru/inf_provision/classifiers_reference/kladr/) с ней можно ознакомиться. Впрочем, не знаю, в каком виде он там лежит, сам не скачивал. Что касается других стран, то тут сказать ничего не могу